# how to create a simple chart drawing library

Tags: c#

I have a followin problem. My task is to create a simple chart drawing library(like Windows Charts for example). I have already tried tu use Graphics class but there are few problems with this approach. When using Graphics i have no control over things that I already drawn. I need a way to interact with drawn objects - to erase a specific point or line from the view, or to make a mouse hover events.
I simply ask for some guidance how to even start.

Comment: You need to keep track of where each "thing" is, then handle mouse events and do hit-testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds kind of like a homework question, but here is an outline of how I would approach this:

You need to create a class type for every different type of thing you want to draw, and have them inherent from a abstract base type. So for instance, you might have a class `DrawableObject`, and then a `Circle : DrawableObject`, `Polygon : DrawableObject` etc, inside of the abstract base class, you would define methods such as `Paint(Graphics g)` and `IsHit(Point p)` or similar, because every time you make a change to your graphics, you will need to clear and re-paint every item. This way when you keep your DrawableObject's in an array, you just need to iterate through them and call the paint method on each. So each painted object will keep the specifics within its own class (such as coordinates, size, etc)

This is how I would get started doing this on WinForms, although if you can use WPF, you could include a WPF control host and then use the WPF shape controls as your items as they can be manipulated and WPF would take care of repainting the surface